# Bot gives TypeError when trying to timeout user via message reaction (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, typeerror

I have been building a discord bot for some time. Currently tring to timeout users if they react with the wrong emoji. My discord bot gives me an error when i try to timeout user via reaction.

```
import random
import discord
from datetime import timedelta

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True
intents.dm_messages = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user}')
    
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
      if message.content.startswith('test'):
        embed=discord.Embed(color=0x00000)
        embed.add_field(name="test", value="test", inline=False)
        msg=await message.channel.send("testmsg",embed=embed)
        await msg.add_reaction("")

@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    embeds = reaction.message.embeds
    embed = embeds[0]
    if reaction.emoji == "" and not user.bot:
        await user.timeout(until=timedelta(minutes=10),reason="lol")
        await reaction.remove(user)

client.run("token")
```

the error I get is the following

```
TypeError: Member.timeout() got some positional-only arguments passed as keyword arguments: 'until'
```

Comment: The error is telling exactly what the problem is; the [timeout](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member%20timeout#discord.Member.timeout) method's `until` argument is positional-only, but you passed it as a keyword argument.

Comment: Ok, but I do not know what to put there for it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically instead of this

```
await user.timeout(until=timedelta(minutes=10),reason="lol")
```

Do this

```
await user.timeout(timedelta(minutes=10),reason="lol")
```

Positional-only arguments mean that you only pass your value as an argument not keyword with a value as an argument.

See [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/) for some dense reading.

See [here](https://youtu.be/R8-oAqCgHag?t=289) for a video on the subject.

Hope that helps.